# MYSQL: from subquery with where

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do this query:

```
SET @NUMBER:=0;
SELECT *, @NUMBER:=@NUMBER+1 AS NUMBER FROM(
    SELECT * 
    FROM CTBQ 
) AS TB1
WHERE TB1.NUMBER > 1
```

but this error happens: Unknown column 'TB1.NUMBER' in 'where clause'

why can't I do this?

can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't see the point of introducing a row number if there is no ordering in your query.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Column aliases are not allowed in the WHERE clause. But it looks like you just need `LIMIT 99999999999999999 OFFSET 1` to skip the first row.

Comment: you can't use alias  in where

Comment: Tried replacing WHERE with HAVING?

Comment: Use another top-level subquery, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3ScRZsJmaq78yQdP7bMh7k/0).

Comment: I need to made one pagging, but I don't want to use mysql limit clause

Answer (score 0):

There is no `NUMBER` column in `TB1` subquery. The column is defined in main query. Therefore you need to use `NUMBER` instead of `TB1.NUMBER`. Also, you can use aliases in `HAVING` clause only. Thus, use folowing:

```
SET @NUMBER:=0;
SELECT *, @NUMBER:=@NUMBER+1 AS `NUMBER` 
FROM
    (SELECT * 
    FROM `measurements` 
) AS TB1
GROUP BY `NUMBER`
HAVING `NUMBER`>1;
```

Note, it is possible to use proposed query without `GROUP BY` clause.